# NetBeans, no me deja crear ni abrir proyectos usando jdk 9+

Tags: java, netbeans

Hasta he estado usando NetBeans (version 8.2) para programar en Java porque me gusta este IDE pero no se porque ya no funciona correctamente.

Doy click a crear un nuevo archivo o proyecto y nada se abre, y cuando intento abrir un proyecto me deja seleccionarlo, pero en cuanto le doy a abrir no hace absolutamente nada.

### Intentos

Ya he probado a borrar todas las carpetas relacionadas con el programa para seguidamente volver a instalarlo pero no ha funcionado, hasta ayer me funcionaba perfectamente, ¿alguna idea de lo que pasa y que puedo hacer?

Comment: solo te falla el netbans y la  jdk te funciona de manera adecuada  , seria bueno que indique que versión de netbens manejas

Comment: si ya intentaste restaurar el pc con un punto de guardado

Comment: No tengo copia de seguridad y perdería muchos datos al hacer eso.

Comment: mira por si de pronto el pc te genero punto de restauración  en ocaciones el computador lo hace

Comment: Tal vez hayas eliminado el proyecto y solo tienes el src, mira en la carpeta del proyecto si tienes 5 carpetas al menos. Espero que te sirva de algo, Saludos

Comment: el  punto de restauración no toca los archivos solo los programa te dejo un link para que vea lo que hace el punto de restauración  https://hipertextual.com/archivo/2013/08/puntos-de-restauracion-de-windows/

Comment: Con no hace absolutamente nada te refieres a que se cierra o a que no abre ningún archivo?

Comment: No abre ningún archivo

Comment: Hola @AlejandroLL, si alguna de las respuestas te sirvió para resolver el problema, por favor márcala como aceptada (incluso si es la tuya propia). De ese modo esta pregunta estará completa. Lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para más información.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Al parecer el programa empezó a utilizar el jdk9 lo cual es la causa del problema pero le he dicho que utilice el jdk1.8.0_151 y ya esta todo solucionado.

Answer (score 3):

Antes de instalar una IDE **debes revisar sus requerimientos**, yo uso Netbeans 8.1 que requiere Java SE Development Kit (JDK) 7 Update 10  y para la versión 8.2, los [requerimientos](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/install.html#requiredsoftware) son:

> - Se requiere Java SE Development Kit (JDK) 8 para instalar NetBeans IDE. Puede descargar la última actualización de JDK 8 en
>     http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
> - Los paquetes NetBeans de PHP y C / C ++ solo requieren que Java Runtime Environment (JRE) 8 se instale y ejecute. Se requiere JDK 8 si
>     planea usar cualquiera de las características de Java.
> - Se requiere JDK 8 para utilizar las características de JavaFX 8 en NetBeans IDE 8.2.

Answer (score 2):

Me pasaba exactamente lo mismo.
Al leer el mensaje de AlejandroLL he mirado en mis programas instalados y tenía dos versiones diferentes de JDK instaladas, eliminé las versiones de JDK 9 (Java 9 y Java SE Development kit 9).
Al volver a abrir Netbeans me ha preguntado si usar la configuración por defecto, ahí dices que 'Si' y va todo de maravilla.

Al parecer había algún conflicto con las versiones 8 y 9 de JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans

Solo se necesita cambiar de nombre a un carpeta que se llama 8.2 por _8.2
para solucionar el problema en netbeans 8.2 de que no carga el historial o mas bien el main, al momento de crear una nueva aplicación esta es la solución.

vas al disco local(c:)\Users\nombre_usuario\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans.

en la carpeta Netbeans encontraras una carpeta con este nombre 8.2 renombrala por _8.2 y listo. no olvides cerrar antes netbeans por que no te dejara renombrar la carpeta.

Primer paso: cierra netbeans.
Segundo Paso: ve a la carpeta netbeans.(arriba te deje la ruta de como llegar)
Tercer Paso: renombra la caperta 8.2 por _8.2 
Cuarto Paso: abre netbeans y crea un nueva api.
quinto Paso: Eres feliz por que ya funciona.